# On the supremum of the union of two bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A,B$ be bounded subsets of an ordered set $S$. Then $A \cup B$ is bounded and $\sup( A \cup B) = \sup \{ \sup A, \sup B \} $.

#### Attempt to solution:

Let $x \in A \cup B$. Then $x \in A $ or $x \in B$. If $x \in A $, then by hypothesis, there are some $u,l \in S$ such that $ l \leq x \leq u$. Similarly, if $x \in B$ we can find $l',u' \in S$ with $l' \leq x \leq u'$. Put $L = \min(l,l')$ and $U = \max(u,u') $. It follows that $L \leq x \leq  U $. Hence, $A \cup B$ is bounded.

Next, since $A \cup B$ is bounded, it must be bounded above. It follows that $A \cup B$ enjoys the Least Upper Bound property and $ \alpha = \sup (A \cup B) $ exists. Hence, $x \leq \alpha $ for all $x \in A \cup B$. If $x \in A$, then $\sup A \leq \alpha$. Similarly, if $x \in B$, we have $\sup B \leq \alpha $. In particular, $\sup\{ \sup A, \sup B \} \leq \alpha $. Furthermore, we have that $x \leq \sup A $ for all $x \in A$ and $x \leq \sup B$ for all $x \in B$. Can I conclude that $x \leq \sup\{ \sup A, \sup B \} $ for all $x \in A \cup B $ ???

Also, I would like to get some feedback on my solution. thanks.

Comment: The problem should probably add the condition that $\sup( A \cup B) = \sup \{ \sup A, \sup B \}$ if and only if $\sup A$ and $\sup B $ exist, from which it doesn't follow automatically that $\sup( A \cup B) $ exists, you would have to prove it.