# If $u\notin E$, then the supremum of $E\cup\{u\}$ is $\sup\{\sup E, u\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$ be an ordered set and $S \supset E $. Let $\alpha  = \sup E \in E$. If $u \notin E$, then we have $ \sup ( E \cup \{u\} ) = \sup\{ \alpha, u \} $.

#### Try:

I know this result follows easy by using [On the supremum of the union of two bounded sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042058/on-the-supremum-of-the-union-of-two-bounded-sets) :

$$\sup ( E \cup \{ u \} ) = \sup \{ \sup E , \sup \{ u \} \} = \sup \{ \alpha, u \}$$
since the supremum of a singleton { x } is always $x$ trivially.

Now, I would like to solve this problem without using the previous problem: This is what I have tried:
Since $u \notin E$, then it follows that $ \alpha \neq u $. Let $A = E \cup \{ u \} $.

If $\alpha < u $, then $\sup\{ \alpha, u \} = u $ trivially. Since $x \leq \alpha $ for all $x \in E$, then we have $x < u $ for all $x \in A$ and since $ u \in A$, it follows at once that $u = \sup A = \sup ( E \cup \{u \} ) $.

If $u < \alpha $, then $\alpha = \sup\{u, \alpha\} $ since $\alpha $ is an upper bound inside the set $\{ u , \alpha \}$. The result follows by the same line of thought of the previous paragraph.

I would like to get feedback. Thanks.

Comment: what if neither $\alpha < u$ nor $u < \alpha,$ i.e. if $\alpha$ and $u$ are not comparable? by "ordered set" do you mean "totally ordered set"? if this is the case then you are correct.

Comment: Early on you seem to assert that $\sup E \in E$ (when you say "then it follows that $\alpha\ne u$). But this is false: take $E=(0,1)$ in the real numbers, for example. - In fact, the hypothesis $u\notin E$ doesn't seem necessary at all to prove this. Assuming, as Krish said, that by "ordered set" you mean totally ordered; if only partially ordered, then it's false, as one can see by say taking $S$ to be the power set of $\{1,2\}$, $E=\{\{1\}\}$, and $u=2$.